# How can i view my dockerized container app that i just set up on Azure?

Tags: azure, docker

I seem to be missing something here.

So i've set up a free account on Azure.  Using their tutorials as a reference, I managed to get the public/private keys set up and i ssh'd into the server.  (this was done after creating a container resource on the portal).  Once in that server I sucessfully ran this command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 dallascaley/get-started:part1
```

I can also verify that it is running by using docker ps command.  I also know that this works fine on my local system so i feel that i am very close to getting my first containerized docker app up and running but I just can't seem to figure out what address i need to go to to view the live app.

According to one post on stack overflow it should be the DNS name that is listed on the resource that starts with 'swarm-master-ip-' but that doesn't work, nor does the IP address listed.  I've looked at every record in my resources list and tried all of the DNS and IP address (most of which are duplicates) and none of them seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause it that you create your container on the master, we should create container on swarm agent. By default we **can't** create container on swarm master.

Once we content to swarm master and run `docker info`, the information like this:

```
root@swarm-master-784816DA-0:~# docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 2
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.19.0-65-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 6.805GiB
Name: swarm-master-784816DA-0
ID: IKDF:RSRH:CXT2:M6ER:KI4R:DYAR:2CZH:FFQX:MCRT:4NZB:CBS4:LNRK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Then we **access the docker swarm cluster**, **set your DOCKER_HOST environment variable** to the local port you configured for the tunnel whit this command `export DOCKER_HOST=:2375` and `docker info`:

```
root@swarm-master-784816DA-0:~# export DOCKER_HOST=:2375
root@swarm-master-784816DA-0:~# docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 1
 swarm-agent-784816DA000001: 10.0.0.5:2375
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 0
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 7.145 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=<not supported>, kernelversion=3.19.0-65-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, storagedriver=overlay
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2017-07-03T01:57:18Z
Plugins: 
 Volume: 
 Network: 
 Log: 
Swarm: 
 NodeID: 
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 
Kernel Version: 3.19.0-65-generic
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.145GiB
Name: 2076070ddfd8
Docker Root Dir: 
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Experimental: false
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
```

Then we run `docker ps` to get the information:

```
root@swarm-master-784816DA-0:~# docker run -d -p 80:80 yeasy/simple-web
0226e9ab3cadf20701f64c02f1f4a42f5fd57fd297722f268db47db1b124ab5c
root@swarm-master-784816DA-0:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
0226e9ab3cad        yeasy/simple-web    "/bin/sh -c 'pytho..."   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        10.0.0.5:80->80/tcp   swarm-agent-784816DA000001/stupefied_snyder
```

Then we can use the **public IP address** or **DNS** of swarm-agent-lb load balancer to access the website.

More information about set environment, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect#connect-to-a-dcos-or-swarm-cluster).

Comment: Does it work for you? please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: where do i find "the local port you configured for the tunnel"  I don't recall configuring this anywhere?

Comment: Ok forget my last comment, i got it to work.  I did exactly as you said using port 2375 because that is the swarm port and using the load balancer IP.  I don't completely understand it but it works so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Azure and the Azure Container Service so I'm trying to answer this based on what I can gather from the documentation.

Since you mentioned `swarm-master-ip` I'm assuming you launched a Swarm cluster in the container service. The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-docker-swarm suggests that there is a Azure Load Balancer automatically set up for the Swarm agent nodes that will route requests to the applications:

> You can now access the application that is running in this container through the public DNS name of the Swarm agent load balancer. You can find this information in the Azure portal.

If there isn't anywhere in the Azure Container Service portal, then somewhere in the Azure service should be the management for the [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) and list the public DNS for it.

Answer (score 0):

The docker container is bound to the host port 80. So from the host, you should be able to hit that running instance, `curl localhost` and get a positive response.
If that works, then assuming this azure instance has a public IP (network interface bound to the public) you could get your IP address with `ifconfig` and from anywhere in the world you can reach your server from http://12.34.56.78 (whatever your external interface IP address is)